# HTML - Adding the script in the head or in the body (to translate the DOM)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am doing the following to translate my html page:

```html
<head>
  <script type="module" src="js/scripts/home.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="hello">Hello world!</h1>
</body>
```

and

```js
import $ from "jquery";

import { t } from "../lib/i18n";

function main() {
  $("#hello").text(t("hello"));
}

main();
```

I do not understand why this work, I thought that, in order to manipulate the DOM, we should wait to get it ready...

By the other hand, if I add the script at the end of the body tag, the look-and-feel is worse, because there is a little timeout before the translation.

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="hello">Hello world!</h1>
  <script type="module" src="js/scripts/home.js"></script>
</body>
```

Another option, with the same behavior, is to include the script at the head but change the js code to:

```js
import $ from "jquery";

import { t } from "../lib/i18n";

function main() {
  $("#hello").text(t("hello"));
}

$(main); // on DOM ready <---------
```

What is the suggested way to go here and why?

Answer (score 2):

See [the MDN documentation for script elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> **defer**
>
> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script
> is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before
> firing DOMContentLoaded.
>
> Scripts with the defer attribute will prevent the DOMContentLoaded
> event from firing until the script has loaded and finished evaluating.
>
> Warning: This attribute must not be used if the src attribute is
> absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would have no
> effect.
>
> The defer attribute has no effect on module scripts — they defer by
> default.

Since it is a module, it is automatically deferred, so won't run until the DOM is ready, thus you don't need to write any JS to explicitly wait for the DOM to be ready.